# Braintree create submerchant unsuccessful but with no errors in the result object

Tags: java, braintree

I wanted to use the Braintree [Marketplace](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+java/guides/marketplace/overview) (I've got the approval and signed to use the marketplace functionality). I used JAVA for my backend and played with the Sandbox account.

I was trying to create a submerchant accorinding to the tutorials in the [overview](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+java/guides/marketplace/overview) and the specific [section](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+java/guides/marketplace/create). E.g., the code I directly copied from the guide is (I'VE ALSO TRIED TO USE MY VALID PERSONAL INFORMATION BELOW):

```
MerchantAccountRequest request = new MerchantAccountRequest().
    individual().
        firstName("Jane").
        lastName("Doe").
        email("jane@14ladders.com").
        phone("5553334444").
        dateOfBirth("1981-11-19").
        ssn("456-45-4567").
        address().
            streetAddress("111 Main St").
            locality("Chicago").
            region("IL").
            postalCode("60622").
            done().
        done().
    funding().
        descriptor("Blue Ladders").
        destination(MerchantAccount.FundingDestination.BANK).
        email("funding@blueladders.com").
        mobilePhone("071101307").
        accountNumber("1123581321").
        routingNumber("071101307").
        done().
    tosAccepted(true).
    masterMerchantAccountId("14ladders_marketplace").
    id("blue_ladders_store");
Result<MerchantAccount> result = gateway.merchantAccount().create(request);
```

I've also tried to use the [testing first name](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+java/reference/general/testing)

```
com.braintreegateway.test.MerchantAccount.Approve
```

so that the creation *should* always succeed. The code snippet is:

```
Result<MerchantAccount> result = gateway.merchantAccount().create(
    new MerchantAccountRequest().
    individual()
        .firstName(com.braintreegateway.test.MerchantAccount.Approve)
        .done()
  );
```

However, in any case, when I tried to check if the result is successful (and if not, what the errors are):

```
logger.info("Is the result successful? " + result.isSuccess());

ValidationErrors errors = result.getErrors();
logger.info("Number of errors returned " + result.getErrors().size());
```

The result.isSuccess() always returns false, while there are no errors in result.getErrors(). I also cannot find any (error) information from the sandbox web account. Any insights what might go wrong? or is this because I haven't *enabled* the marketplace functionality?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

<sub>I work at Braintree. If you have more questions, you can always [get in touch with our support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/). It looks like you already have an open ticket with us and got a response, but I'll post his here for others who have the same problem.</sub>

You're looking for `result.getErrors().getAllDeepValidationErrors()` not just `result.getErrors()`.

For more information on this type of failure, see the [validation errors page in the Braintree docs](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+java/reference/general/error-handling/validation-errors#all-errors-on-all-levels).